# Eclipse&Maven - The import org.hibernate.boot.cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I am building an Maven&Spring&Hibernate&JSF project on Eclipse.While compiling the program I have

> StandardServiceRegistryBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
>   The import org.hibernate.boot.cannot be resolved

errors.

Main class is as follows:

```
package com.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.data.Person;

public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args){

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    System.out.println("CFG and hbm files loaded successfully.");//just to test

    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build());

    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    System.out.println("Transaction began");//just to test

    Person newPerson = new Person();
    newPerson.setFirstName("aa");
    newPerson.setLastName("bbb");
    newPerson.setGender("Male");
    newPerson.setAge(2);

    session.save(newPerson);
    session.flush();

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("aaa");//just to test

}
}
```

pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring-Hibernate-JSF-MySQL-Example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
<!-- Generic properties -->
 <java.version>1.6</java.version>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a Hibernate library - looks like Hibernate 4 provides this.

Comment: I have planned to build project using hibernate 3.I guess, I should modify the main class.Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the broken classpath;

```
Package explorer > Plug-in tools > Update classpath.
```

Or your Hibernate jar is not well extracted from the zip file. For controll, from `Project Explorer` try to expand your Hibernate jar. If you can't expand probably it's corrupted. Try to add jar again.

Comment: Still gives the same error.I guess, there is something else wrong with it.But thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: I don't see Plug-in tools